# Angular 5: check for new messages from a Django API at the back

Tags: angular

I have a django API that checks for new messages. It basically instructs client application what to do (such as refresh a certain component) or simply notify the user what has happened to data somewhere else.

I need the check to happen every minute. Or what would be the way to notify the front-end automatically the front-end users?

Comment: Sounds like the job for a WebSocket.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to poll for changes just once every minute, you can simply use `setInterval` and dispatch your request inside of its callback.

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.pollForChanges();
}, 60 * 1000);
```

If you want to have your server *push* changes to the front-end, instead of the front-end polling for the changes, you can use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). However, that will require both front-end and back-end work - you need a WebSockets server and WebSockets client to connect to it.

Comment: I knew that but I was hoping for something that would work purely at the back.Thanks still thoug.

Comment: Tanks Ganev. I seem to have gotten the handle of it. I am on python 3.4 and couldn't install channels. Will install it on a new machine and give it a shot.